# Как правильно применить регулярное выражение?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью регулярного выражения для строки:

```
re-medbedb-re-darksun-re-bit8k-khorosho-li-chto-kazhdyi-den-sozdayutsya-novye-kriptovalyuty-20161102t054454811z
```

вырезать все подстроки, начинающиеся с re-, и дату с конца строки, оставив только середину? Количество подстрок с re- неизвестное количество.

В данном случае, на выходе хочется получить вот это:

```
khorosho-li-chto-kazhdyi-den-sozdayutsya-novye-kriptovalyuty
```

Понимаю, что можно заморочится с рекурсивным sub_str, но фигня какая-то. Регулярным выражением получится красиво, но.. там для меня полнейших темный лес пока -- сам не разберусь и за неделю.

```
$re = '/^.+-re-.+?-(.+)-\d+.+/m';
$str = 're-medbedb-re-darksun-re-bit8k-re-dfsfdf-khorosho-li-chto-kazhdyi-den-sozdayutsya-novye-kriptovalyuty-20161102t054454811z
re-medbedb-re-darksun-re-bit8k-dsdsdsd-li-chto-kazhdyi-den-sozdayutsya-novye-kriptovalyuty-20161102t054454811z
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: У вас разве в элементе $matches[1] не то что вам было нужно?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/re-[^-]*-/","",$str);
```